# Bootstrap Navbar Will Open, But Not Close

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

Here is the code I am using:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="/application/themes/dcc_theme/img/DiscoveryChurchColorado.png" alt="Discovery Church Colorado, Colorado Springs, CO" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="http://concrete.metooplace.com/about" target="_self" class="">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="http://concrete.metooplace.com/serve" target="_self" class="">Serve</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="http://concrete.metooplace.com/events" target="_self" class="">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-selected nav-path-selected"><a href="http://concrete.metooplace.com/give" target="_self" class="nav-selected nav-path-selected">Give</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The url for the test page is http://concrete.metooplace.com

The problem is that on a mobile device you can click the menu button and the menu will expand, but it won't close if you click it again.

This was working fine. I must have inadvertently changed something, or there is a conflict in my javascript, but I can't seem to figure out what happened and I need a fresh set of eyes to check it out.

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834). You need to use a different version of jQuery [2.2.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js) or [1.12.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.js). Also, `navbar-right` goes with `navbar-nav` not `navbar-collapse` see [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: I have changed the jquery version to 2.2.1 and 1.12.1 and it doesn't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the version of the Bootstrap JS. I changed it to a 3.3.6 CDN version and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this issue and it was simply because the file bootstrap.min.js was being called in both the `head` and `body`.

Hopefully this saves someone some time

Answer (score 2):

In my case, bootstrap.min.js was called in both index.html and angular.json. So, I retained just one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Looks like you're using $ before you've included jQuery.
Make sure your scripts are in the right order and you should be fine!

Comment: yep, oversight. moved it and still doesn't work. I shouldn't even have to use that extra code because it was, and has in the past worked with a standard Bootstrap dist.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your HTML code and the problem is that you are trying to call the code below before including your jQuery file.

```
<!--js/jquery stuff-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
});
</script>
```

Please put the code block after include your jQuery file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I hope it will work!

Comment: yeah, that was an oversight. still doesn't fix it. Also, out of the box, I shouldn't have to add this extra code. I was just trying this to see if it would fix it. It was working without it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be even if you're using an older version of jQuery. I've figured it out that, after I made several changes in my code (I'm building a wordpress website), if you tried to combine some of the older version of jQuery (until 1.7) with some version of bootstrap.js (from version 3.2) generates this kind of error.